# Why does casting cause the error to go away?

Tags: typescript

In the code below, when I include `as Response`, the error goes away. Why? When I don't cast, I get this error:

> Type '{ header: { 'x: number; }; text: string;
> }' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': accepted,
> badRequest, body, charset, and 47 more.ts(2740) index.d.ts(93, 9): The
> expected type comes from property 'response' which is declared here on
> type 'ResponseError'

```
err: {
  response: {
    header: {
      'x': 20,
    },
    text: 'Too many calls.',
  } as Response,
},
```

Why would casting with `as Response` cause the error to go away? I mean, I still haven't specified those ~50 properties.

Comment: Can you post a valid code & more context. ?

Comment: It's not *really* a cast. It's more like an assertion, which in some cases, TypeScript will check if the assertion doesn't match the target at all.

Comment: The *only* thing `as` does is make the error go away. It does nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: You should use `as` with caution, and try to avoid it if at all possible.

> *Why would casting with `as Response` cause the error to go away?*

Because type *assertions* are not guaranteed to be typesafe.

```
const obj: { x: number, y: number } = { x: 1 } as { x: number, y: number }
// fine
```

The point of the `as` keyword is to tell the compiler that you, the code author, know better than compiler does. This may be to provide the compiler some information that it cannot know on its on, or for you to lie to the compiler.

Your posted code may be fine if this is fixture data for test run. Maybe the function you are testing accepts a `Response` type, but only accesses a few fields. You could use `as Response` here to tell typescript to treat this as a full `Response` object, while defining only the important fields. The drawback is runtime failures if you don't provide what's required.

[Documentation on type assertions here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

---

Instead you could actually [create an instance of response.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response)

```
const myResponse = new Response('Too many calls.', {
  headers: { x: '20' }
});

function doStuff(res: Response) {
  //...
}
doStuff(myResponse) // works
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwEoFMIAdwRTAvDMFAdxlQyxQAoByAFRBHgEMwEZgmAbTiAOmoA0MAN4AoGDAAWKJgBMUAJwgAuETAAeq6gCYADNRgBfUYYCUAblGiAZgFcwwKAEtwMWSADKUW9euUFaKpkmJAopiLiMAD0UbxxJqLuXj5+iMEUpkA)

Comment: You're correct; this is in a unit test. If I don't want to specify the 50 properties, and I really shouldn't be using `as`, is there a better approach for this specific situation?

Comment: You could create possibly create a `Response` instance like `new Response()` and then configure it. Or you could change the signature of the function that takes this object to take an object type that has just the fields you care about like `foo(response: { header: Record<string, string>, text: string })`. You probably want the first one of those ideas.

Comment: Ok, so the real answer to my question about why `as` works is: "tell typescript to treat this as a full Response object, while defining only the important fields." Thank you.